# Grub can't access my root partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, bios

I have an Samsung RF511-SD6BR notebook wich I usd to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10, but its HD died. I installed a 120GB Kingston A400 SSD and was planning to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. As this notebook has a very limited BIOS setup (I can choose between BIOS and EFI, but there aren't any options to customize EFI like "Fast Boot", "Secure mode" or "Compatibility mode") and it used BIOS originally I decided to continue booting this way. I installed Ubuntu first, with the following partition MBR table:

- sda1: 100MB Fat32 boot flag (later I discovered its needed only for EFI).
- sda2: 60GB Windows (unformatted)
- sda5: 18GB / (ext4)
- sda6: 8GB swap
- sda7: 34GB /home (ext4)

Ubuntu installed normally, but when I tried to boot it dropped to grub rescue. When I tried to ls the extended partitions I got he message 'no such partition'. So I deleted my root partition and created a primary partition in its place with gparted, and reinstalled Ubuntu getting the following partitions:

- sda1: 100MB Fat32 (empty)
- sda2: 60GB Windows (formatted with NTFS by gparted, empty) with boot flag
- sda4: 18GB / (ext4)
- sda5: 8GB swap
- sda6: 34GB /home (ext4)

Again Ubuntu installed fine but when booting I drop to Grub rescue and if I ls any partition I got "Unknown filesystem" in all partitions even after loading module ext2. Also tried boot-repair and got the same result.

The most of last boot-repair report (sdb is the Ubuntu install usb stick):
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t9Qk6NR7Kr/

How can I solve this? I didn't even installed Windows and it isn't booting. Is there a firmware bug affecting Grub?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI/BIOS from Samsung to latest version? And many SSD need firmware updates also.

Comment: If your BIOS have an old CSM module, grub may has some accessible range limits.  I would try to have a 500-1GB /boot partition in the beginning of the disk and boot from it.